# Symfony 2 Embedding Collections and Entity FieldTypes to Persist a Join Table (1:M M:1 1:M)

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm struggling through a scenario and may be missing the final piece.

> **Person** has many *abilities*
>
> **Abilities** have properties of years, and commercial experience (optional)
>
> An **ability** has a *type* (ex: Daily / Monthly, etc.
>
> **Person** -- 1:M --  **Abilities**  M:1 Person / M:1 Type -- **Type** 1:M Abilities

*Person / Abilities have cascade persist / remove and also orphan removal set.*

**User Interaction**

The user creates their initial profile, they go to the abilities page and click checkboxes which relate to their abilities, a corresponding (optional) checkbox for their commercial experience, and a dropdown for the years of experience.

**Intention:**

When a user selects their abilities and submit - the corresponding abilities are associated with the user (plus any properties). Then persisted, ignoring any rows in which the abilitytitle is not checked (disabled, etc).

**ABILITIES FORM: Updated**

```
$builder
->add('abilitytitle', 'collection', array(
        'by_reference' => false,
        'type' => new AbilityTitleType(),
        'data_class'   => 'AppBundle\Entity\AbilityTitle',
    ))
->add('commercialexperience','collection',array(
    'type' => 'checkbox', 
    'allow_add' => true,
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Commercial Experience',
        'required'  => false,)
))
->add('experience','collection',array(
    'type' => 'choice',
    'allow_add' => true,
    'options' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Please select',
        'choices' => 
            array(
             '1-2' => '1-2',
             '3-4' => '3-4',
            ),
    'required'  => false, 
    )
))
```

*For the form, I have Experience and Commercial Experience printed out manually coinciding with the abilities information. I created an AbilityTitleType and inserted it as a collection, but it seemed to put me off track.*

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public function newUserAction(Request $request)
{
    $person= new Person();

    $form = $this->createForm(new PersonEntry(),$person);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($person);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('qualifications'));
    }

    return $this->render('AppBile:User:newPerson.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

*This is a generic form flow*
**AbilityTitleType**

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{ 
    $builder
        ->add('abilityname', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:AbilityTitle',
                'property' => 'abilityname',
                'multiple' => true, 
                'expanded' => true, 
                'required'  => false, 
                'label' => 'Please select claims in which you have experience'
            ));
}
public function getName()
{
    return 'abilitytitle';
}
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBile\Entity\AbilityTitle'
    ));
}
```

**Issue: Ability Title displays blank in the form, when embedded**

My getters and setters are typical to the associations and can be provided as desired, with short cuts on users and abilities.

**The problem**

I am stuck with the error "The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class... given as ArrayCollection" for my ability titles. I imagine this is due to the multi-line insert as the dummy code below inserts fine. I believe my issue is concerning collections, embedding, and the entityfield type.

*Am I looking at a scenario where each row is an entity in itself, and I need to catch the data received by the form, persist each separately?*

A collection of embedded entity forms, where the rows may vary by the number of rows abilities could contain? If so, I'm not quite visualizing it!

Thanks for any pointers and for looking! Happy to upload more code if its necessary.

```
// DUMMY CODE - Inserts Fine  
for($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    $person= $em->find('person', 1);
    $person_abilities->setExperience(rand(1,10))
       ->setCommercialExperience(rand(1,10));
    $ability= $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getRepository('AppBundle:AbilityTitle')
       ->findOneById(rand(1,3));
}
$potential->addPerson_Abilities($person_abilities);
$ability->addPerson_Abilities($person_abilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you have to set the `data_class` option.

For Example:

```
->add('test', 'collection', array(
        'type'               => new TestFormType(),
        'options'            => array(
            'data_class'   => 'TestBundle\Entity\Test',
        ),
    )
);
```

EDIT: Forgot the other stuff. You may be interested in reading [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) (scroll down to `Doctrine: Cascading Relations and saving the "Inverse" side`).

Comment: Embedded ability type as a collection, it displays as a _blank area_ on the form. Updated the abilities form and added AbilityTitleType.